# Alert on Azure gateway for application hosted on Azure VM

Tags: azure, alert, azure-virtual-machine

I have to create a alert on a application which is hosted on Azure VM configured which is accessed via Azure gateway. Whenever application goes down ( any response code other than 200) have to send email to specific group of emails.

I tried it with "backend health" active log in Configure signal logic inside alert configuration in gateway but have not got any activity log over there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup an alert based on the "Failed Requests" metric.

Details on how here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics